# What is causing intermittent long execution times for DynamoDB operations

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

We are experiencing intermittent DynamoDB execution times, taking consistently just over 10 seconds. This is happening roughly once every hour or three.

- The DynamoDB operations are called from a Node.js Lambda (either getItem or updateItem)
- The AWS SDK DynamoDB instance instantiation happens once outside of the Lambda handler
- The Lambda and DynamoDB are in the same VPC with a DynamoDB endpoint enabled
- The Lambda is triggered by a DynamoDB stream from another DynamoDB table which can happen multiple times a second
- The tables are set to PAY_PER_REQUEST
- The Partition Key is unique and we are getting concurrency of 4 Lambdas
- We have given the Lambda 2560MB of memory
- We have tried setting the BATCH_SIZE of the stream from 1 to 10 but it never prevents the intermittent long execution time
- We have enabled AWS SDK logging and can see on the long spike times that the DynamoDB call has been retried once - the duration on these occasions is consistently just over 10 seconds
- We have set the AWS SDK timeout from 5 secs to  2 secs and still see the 10 second delay
- We have maxRetries on the table set to 10

The cause for the consistent 10 second timing of the long spikes is hard to figure out. If anyone has any other idea to try out or advice it would be much appreciated. We are also liaising with DynamoDB, Lambda and Networking AWS support departments but so far they haven't figured out what is going on.

Much thanks,

Sam

Comment: Can you share the logs showing the retry?

Comment: Hey Maurice, the log from the AWS.config.logger reads - [AWS dynamodb 200 1 retries 10.049s] getItem ({ tableName: xxxxx, Key: { xxxx: { S: xxxx }, { xxxx: { S: xxxx } } )

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with dynamodb and not your lambda. Can you update the read/write capacity units?

Comment: Please log the param AWS.DynamoDB.retryDelayOptions. The default retry time set in the SDK is 50ms but it sounds suspiciously like your client is retrying after 10s. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015113/aws-dynamodb-throttled-write-request-handling/55022506#55022506

Comment: @Mickers Thanks for the help. We have the tables set to PAY_PER_REQUEST which removes any limits on read write capacity I believe.

Comment: @F_SO_K We have some retry logs now and the values for retryDelay in both of the last 10 sec spikes seem low:-

Comment: What are they? There is more than one value for retryDelayOptions, its an object not a number.

Comment: PAY_PER_REQUEST is not immune to throttling. DynamoDB tries to handle changing throughput, but it doesn't do so perfectly. If you have a very spikey load that goes up quickly, you can still get throttled.

Comment: @F_SO_K Thanks! I'll get the log u requested but here is the retry event error log: 
error:
   { TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 5000ms
       at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:86:34)
       at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:443:8)
       at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
     message: 'Connection timed out after 5000ms',
     code: 'TimeoutError',
     time: 2021-01-22T02:02:54.017Z,
     region: 'eu-west-1',
     hostname: 'dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
     retryable: true,
     retryDelay: 12.354436190407469 }

Comment: @F_SO_K I tried logging out the retryDelayOptions and it comes back as an empty object with no values for base or customBackOff

Comment: @F_SO_K RE the R/W Capacity - As I said it is set to PAY_PER_REQUEST, you mentioned it can still get throttled in PPR mode so do you have any recommendations on how to prevent this? Thanks.